# Specify which config to use in FuelPHP tasks

Tags: fuelphp

In FuelPHP's config folder I have a "development" directory and a "production" directory and everything seems to work well for pages viewed from the controller

But for Tasks and Unit Tests I can't seem to figure out how to specify which config to use. I have to put the config in the /app/fuel/config directory or it won't be seen. (I can't put it in the /app/fuel/config/development/ directory for example)

Is there somewhere in my unit tests and tasks where I can specify which config directory to use?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the the environment like this:

```
$ FUEL_ENV=production php oil refine migrate
```

The documentation show it here: http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/oil/intro.html#/environments